# How separate L and R channel to out 2 different audio sources (programs) at same time on L and R?

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

Is it possible to separate sound output from different programs works at same time throught L and R audio channels respectively with one sound card on the linux (armbian ubuntu) device like Nano pi, orange pi, raspberry pi due to alsa asound.config?

Answer (score 1):

Works! Sip on L, player on R

```
pcm.dmix_stream
{
    type dmix
    ipc_key 321456 
    ipc_key_add_uid true
    slave.pcm "hw:2,0"
}

pcm.ch1 {
    type plug
    slave {
        pcm dmix_stream 
        channels 2
    }
    ttable.0.0 1    
}

pcm.ch2 {
    type plug
    slave {
        pcm dmix_stream 
        channels 2
    }
    ttable.0.1 1    
}

pcm.!default
{
    type asym
    playback.pcm
    {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "ch1"
    }
    capture.pcm 
    {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "hw:2,0"
    }
}
```